# How to specify another disk for fs.readdir(path) in Electron-vue app?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

## Problem:

I have a breadcrumbs component (I'm using file explorer functionality from [this project](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/wander)). The problem is I don't know how to change the disk it's displaying.

When I click on any path in it, I get this:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Path does not exist`

So in ls.js file I changed this code:

```
export function readdir (path) {
  return pathExists(path)
    ? fs.readdir(path)
    : Promise.reject(new Error('Path does not exist'))
}
```

To this code to see what it's trying to read:

```
export function readdir (path) {
  return fs.readdir(path)
}
```

So it turns out it's hardcoded to display `C:` disk. I don't know how to make it dynamic (to display content of any specified disk).

- Right now if I, for example, click on `C: > Users` path in the breadcrumbs component, I get:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'E:\Users'`

- I've tried doing this: `fs.readdir("/" + path)` but it gives me this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'E:\C:\Users\`

---

- The project folder is located on that **E:** disk
- while the breadcrumbs displaying contents of **C:** disk

---

## ls.js file:

```
import fs from 'fs-extra'
import { join } from 'path'

/**
 * Get Array for path contents. Checks if path exists
 * @param  {String} path
 * @return {Promise}
 */
export function readdir (path) {
  return  fs.readdir(path)
}

/**
 * Alias of fs.existsSync
 * @param  {String} path
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
export function pathExists (path) {
  return fs.existsSync(path)
}

/**
 * Get path stat
 * @param  {String} path
 * @return {Promise}
 */
export function stat (path) {
  return fs.stat(path)
}

/**
 * Take in file path and return contents with stat
 * @param  {String} path
 * @return {Array}
 */
export default path => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const contents = []

    readdir(path).then(files => {
      let statsPromises = []

      files.forEach(file => {
        statsPromises.push(stat(join(path, file)))
      })

      Promise.all(statsPromises).then(stats => {
        stats.forEach((stat, i) => {
          contents.push({
            name: files[i],
            path: join(path, files[i]),
            stat
          })
        })

        resolve(contents)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the **`Breadcrumbs.vue`** you will see the following method at the botton.

```
placePath () {
    return this.$store.state.Place.path
}
```

There you can see that the path is taken from the state. The state is in **`Place.js`** file.

This path in state is initialized in **`Place.vue`** file. There you'll see a method as follows.

```
load (path = this.$electron.remote.app.getPath('home')) {
    path = join(path)
    this.$store.dispatch('getContents', path).then(() => {
      this.$store.commit('setPlacePath', path)
    }, err => {
      console.error(err)
      this.$route.push('/')
    })
  }
```

The path is coming from the following line. 
**`this.$electron.remote.app.getPath('home')`**

Electron [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname) for the above **`app.getPath()`** method is as follows.

> #### `app.getPath(name)`
>
> - `name` String
>
> Returns `String` - A path to a special directory or file associated
>   with `name`. On failure an `Error` is thrown.
>
> You can request the following paths by the name:
>
> - `home` User's home directory.
> - `appData` Per-user application data directory, which by default points to:   * `%APPDATA%` on Windows   * `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` or
>     `~/.config` on Linux   * `~/Library/Application Support` on macOS
> - `userData` The directory for storing your app's configuration files, which by   default it is the `appData` directory appended with your
>     app's name.
> - `temp` Temporary directory.
> - `exe` The current executable file.
> - `module` The `libchromiumcontent` library.
> - `desktop` The current user's Desktop directory.
> - `documents` Directory for a user's "My Documents".
> - `downloads` Directory for a user's downloads.
> - `music` Directory for a user's music.
> - `pictures` Directory for a user's pictures.
> - `videos` Directory for a user's videos.
> - `logs` Directory for your app's log folder.
> - `pepperFlashSystemPlugin` Full path to the system version of the Pepper Flash plugin.

So those are the options you have as the starting directory.

UPDATE:

**`this.$electron.remote.app.getAppPath()`** will return the current application directory.

```
load (path = this.$electron.remote.app.getAppPath()) {
    path = join(path)
    this.$store.dispatch('getContents', path).then(() => {
      this.$store.commit('setPlacePath', path)
    }, err => {
      console.error(err)
      this.$route.push('/')
    })
  }
```

UPDATE 2:

Please note that I'm new to electron as well. It seems like app.getPath method is used to get the path application is running. If you want a different path you can just hard code it there.

Example:

Note **'/home/rajind'** hardcoded as default value for path parameter.

In `Place.js file`,

```
getContents ({ commit }, path = '/home/rajind') {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ls(path).then(contents => {
        commit('setContents', contents)
        resolve()
      }, err => {
        reject(err)
      })
    })
  }
```

and in `Place.vue` file,

```
 load (path = '/home/rajind') {
    path = join(path)
    this.$store.dispatch('getContents', path).then(() => {
      this.$store.commit('setPlacePath', path)
    }, err => {
      console.error(err)
      this.$route.push('/')
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that it automatically gets the path on disk `C:`, and if the project is located on a different disk (for example, disk `E:`) it throws that error because it always trying to get the path on disk `C:`. Do you happen to know how to specify the `E:` disk instead of default `C:` disk?

Comment: @Un1 updated the answer. Try that. For me, it gave the current working dir. Unfortunately, I'm on Ubuntu so can't test on Windows. I ran on /media instead of /home and it gave me /media path.

Comment: Yeah that worked, it gets the app directory and the Breadcrumbs component works now. But is this all I can do with this? Can I for example specify the `E:/` root path? Or something like `E:/testFolder` instead of the app folder?   Documentation says that `getAppPath` method returns `String - The current application directory`. So I suppose I cannot use that for specifying a different path?

Comment: @Un1 it seems like you can directory give a path there. Let me try that one

Comment: @Un1 see the update above. Worked for me. Try hardcoding a path like that.

Comment: @Un1 If you are getting an error as no-unused-vars remove the import `import { remote } from 'electron'` from Place.js

Comment: @Un1 Cheers bro!